# My program is stopping

Tags: c++

This is my class,and my problem is when I call the constructor

> Eveniment e1(1,m1);

with parameters in main method, my program is stopping and I don't know why. M1 is an object of IntrareCAlendar.

```
class Eveniment{
private:
    const int id;
    IntrareCalendar data;
    char* detalii;
    int static nrIntrari;

public:
    Eveniment(int nr,IntrareCalendar ic) :id(nr){
        this->data = ic;
        nrIntrari++;
    }

    ~Eveniment(){
        if (this->detalii != NULL)
            delete[]this->detalii;

    }
};
```

What should I do? thanks a lot!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ‘*What should I do?*’ You should read [this](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: What Biffen is trying to point out is that we do not have a definition for `IntrareCalendar ic`.  While it's possible to perhaps find flaws in this code as  written (as Bathsheba has pointed out one issue), imagine if you had a copy constructor for IntrareCalendar which said `while (true) {}` or somesuch...so that it would infinite loop on `this->data = ic;`.  We'd have no way of knowing.  We also don't know what "my program is stopping" means--infinite looping? crashing? do you know what line it crashed on?  Consider these issues when posting questions...give complete code and more details.

Answer (score 5):

You never set `detalii` to anything valid. It remains *uninitialised* - it is **not** initialised to a particular value automatically. You *could* set it to `nullptr` in your constructor. (Don't use `NULL` in C++.)

Your destructor calls `delete[]` on that member, but no `new[]` has been called prior to that. As such the behaviour of your program is undefined.

Also, consider using `static std::atomic<int>` as the type for `nrIntarari` in case multiple threads instantiate an `Eveniment`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!God bless you!

Comment: In addition, if you need a destructor, you will also need a copy constructor and an assignement operator (Google "The Rule of Three").  Prefer to declare `detalii` as either `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` (depending on your needs).  If desperate, declare it as `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`.  With any of those choices, you won't need a destructor, and copy/assign will either work correctly (string/vector), or simply not exist (unique_ptr).  All three choices would also have correctly initialized `detalii`, so you wouldn't have had a problem.

Comment: It turns out you need to Google "Rule of Three C++" :-).  But [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) is a good link.